# How to Omit Matches from htaccess Regular Expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sample-([a-z][a-z]).php /state.php?m=$1
RewriteRule ^sample-([a-z^-]+).php /city.php?m=$1
```

I have two regular expressions in my htaccess file, which look for a state (two alphabetical characters, for example "sample-tx.php") and city (any sum of alphabetical characters and dashes, for example "sample-new-bedford.php").

These expressions work great right now, but I need help with two things:

1. For the state expression, how would I omit "az" and "tx", so when someone goes to "sample-az.php" or "sample-tx.php" they are not redirected?
2. Same question as #1, except this time for cities. How would I omit "houston" and "new bedford", so when someone goes to "sample-houston.php" or "sample-new-bedford.php" they are not redirected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(?!...)` [negative assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that.

```
RewriteRule ^sample-(?!az|tx)([a-z][a-z]).php /state.php?m=$1
```

Write them immediately before the character matching group. It would work the same for the cities.